# Como não aparecer valor de lixo quando puxar um dado do banco com PHP que seja nulo

Tags: php, sql-server, data

Estou puxando um valor VARCHAR do banco , que eu converto ele para aparecer em formato de DATA , contanto quando o valor é branco no meu banco, ele me puxa um numero "31/12/1969" . Como posso solucionar isso ?

Como eu estou transformando esse valor :

```
*CONEXÃO COM O BANCO + SQL DO SELECT 

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>
<center><b>Data</b></center>
    </th>
</thead>
<?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<tr>

<td> ?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['DT_FATURAMENTO']??'')); ?>
</td>
<?php     }   ?>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verificando se o valor de `$row['DT_FATURAMENTO']` é vazio antes de passá-lo para a função `strtotime`.

Você tentou fazer isso:

```
strtotime($row['DT_FATURAMENTO'] ?? '')
```

Mas:

- Utilizou o operador de coalescência nula, `??`, que verificará se o primeiro parâmetro é **nulo**, não **vazio** (algo vazio é não nulo);
- Se for nulo, passa como parâmetro a *string* `''`, que é JUSTAMENTE a que você não quer passar;

Parece que escreveu esse trecho de código e nem parou para analisar o que, de fato, tinha feito.

Você deve mudar a condição, considerando `$data` o valor em questão:

```
<?= empty($data) ? 'Indefinida' : date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data)) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso é data default para Unix, com ajuste do fuso horário (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 +/- Horas do fuso horário).

Para solucionar o problema basta condicionalmente não converter para data caso o varchar seja nulo.